# I can't load any project after updating Android Studio to v2.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't load any project after updating Android Studio to v2.3. Here is a picture of the error:

[image]
and it reads:

```
Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: 
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: 
com/android/tools/idea/gradle/invoker/GradleInvoker$AfterGradleInvocationTask [Plugin: com.drakklord.gradle.metric.core]
```

After I tried to uninstall the Checkstyle plugin and reinstall Android Studio, I still get the same error. I have updated JDK to 1.8 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this in a similar thread:

• Close Android Studio

• Go to the directory home_dir/.AndroidStudio/system/cache

• Remove all the files in the cache directory.

• Then restart IntelliJ / Android Studio

I'd suggest making a backup of anything before removing.

Comment: Thank you. Deleting the cache folder do the trick. If anyone has the same problem remember to **export settings** before delete the cache folder and restore after this.

Comment: Glad it worked! Thanks for the additional tip and follow up.

Answer (score 12):

After removed cache directory also if it is not working, then look at the Terminal for error.

If it says,

```
[  96470]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null
```

Then it is the problem with some plugins that you already installed in the IDE.

In my case it was BlackBerry Pugin for Android development. I just removed it from plugins and it worked.

Click on plugins from the bottom right dropdown and uninstall the plugin that you manually installed.

Comment: Mine was gradle.. Disabled it from the same menu, then ran android studio. Re-enabled it when Android studio running. Required restart. Now all working fine.

Comment: As I said in the main question, before removing the cache folder I tried to uninstall the  CheckStyle plugin. So it looks like the real problem was this pluggin. But Android Studio didn't work until I removed the cache folder.

Comment: Looks like both cache removal and plugin removal solves the issue based on the need. Logtrace should be read completely before any particular action.