# Android Studio 2.3 Project Creation Error - GradleInvoker

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I have updated to android Studio 2.3.1,

When I create a Project I get an Error as below :

```
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/invoker/GradleInvoker$AfterGradleInvocationTask [Plugin: net.rim.tools.ajde]
```

[image]
I don't know what the problem is,

I just reinstalled the Android Studio,
opened it and created a Project.

It gives this error and only creates the folder with the project name at the dir, it don't actually creates the project.

I'm Stuck at this Screeen.

[image]

I also refered other Questions and solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608252/i-cant-load-any-project-after-updating-android-studio-to-v2-3), but no Luck.

Comment: please update your android studio 2.3.1

Comment: @SrinivasKeerthiprakasam, I did that first, I got the same error, that's why reinstalled the Android studio.

Comment: @SrinivasKeerthiprakasam Read the Last line of my Question.

Comment: @SrinivasKeerthiprakasam and also compare the plugin name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141438/discussion-between-nirav-madariya-and-srinivas-keerthiprakasam).

Comment: Just remove that plugin(Blackberry plugin).It will work fine.Or follow this link https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/bb_android_studio_plugin_tool.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing following solved my Problem.

From the welcome screen of Android Studio, click > `Configure` (Right Bottom) then,

Expand `Build, Execution, Deployment` > Required Plugins > Remove BlackBerry Plugin.

BlackBerry Plugin was stopping Android Studio from loading the Project.